# Matrix multiplicatiion

Tags: algorithm, matrix, dynamic-programming

I was reading Introduction to Algorithms by Cormen on dynamic programming.

The ordering of matrices is important to perform a matrix multiplication. If I multiplied a number of matrices and come up with the best result, how to keep that result optimal by adding a matrix to the series ?

Answer (score 1):

If you have:

```
DP[i, j] = minimum cost of multiplying matrices i to through j
```

then `DP[1, n]` will be your answer.

To find `DP[1, n + 1]`, just apply the same recurrence you used to build the table:

```
DP[1, n + 1] = min   {DP[1, k] + DP[k + 1, n + 1] + multiplication cost}
            1<=k<n+1
```

This will be `O(n)`.